# Eclipse can't run MPI project

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, parallel-processing, mpi

i installed eclipse 64-bit for parallel application develper and i created MPI hello world C Project and `Toolchain:Linux Gcc`. i installed mpich2 on my ubuntu 12.04 so that i set project setting :

`Include Path :/usr/include/mpich2

Library name : mpich

Library search path: /usr/lib/mpich2/lib

MPI compile command : mpicc.mpich2

MPI link command: mpicc.mpich2`

i want run and debug project on local so i add Parallel Application to `Profile Configuratuin` but i had  Launcher Error window bellow when i set `Target System Configuration :MPICH2-Generic-interactive` and i select **Local** to `connection Type`.

`Failed to create control for the dynamic tab "Basic Options"`

`Reason:Undefined attribute "noLocalOption" in widgetType`